# Webkit javascript evaluation uses different document object?

Tags: objective-c, webkit, document

I'm hosting a webkit frame in my objective-C application and trying to execute some javascript on the loaded document using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString.  Every call I make to document.getElementsByTagName('*') or document.getElementsByTagName('a') returns 0 length collections, regardless of the page I load in my webview.  Other document methods seem to work (document.title, document.location.href, etc).  The script returns the correct value in Safari, just not in my webview.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webview didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame{ 
        NSLog(@"anchor elements: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('a').length + '';"]); 
}
```

(in case you're wondering, the + '' is used to coerce the length into a string)

I've also tried

```
[[webView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:@"document.getElementsByTagName('*').length + '';"]
```

with the same results returning 0. 
Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

After much head smashing, I figured out the problem-- calls to document.getElement* from a different thread return no elements.  Other methods still seem to work.